# JQuery: How do you use live with the post function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When load the new html from a post function I lose all of my click bindings. I read that i could use live to keep all the bindings but can't find any examples where live is used with post. Here is my code:

```
$('.GroupHeader').unbind('click').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        TemplateEditor.SelectGroupClicked($(this));
    });
```

Comment: Can we see your .live() code?

Comment: Tip: It's a code convention that only constructors should start with a capital letter in JavaScript and some other languages. I recommend you to rename you "Obj" parameter =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind your click event handlers, i.e.:

```
$(selector).live('click', function () {
  //...
});
```

Instead of :

```
$(selector).click(function () { // or $(selector).bind('click', ...
  //...
});
```

In that way, doesn't matter your elements are replaced, the events will still work, because [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works with [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/).

Comment: @Luke101: `live` doesn't work like that, `live` lets you bind events, and `'post'` is not an event. The `AddGroup` function should stay like before your edit, you should change the code where you add the click event handlers....

Comment: Sorry for all the questions. I have changed again for the click event. But this way still does not work.

Comment: Actually, Ill take that back..This does work. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK..I have got a really good working version. Would you have any suggestions?